# Stop fixed from 100px to footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

now I have a div that becomes fixed on scroll. I need to remove fixed when I'm 100px from the footer.

Below my code:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
     var y = jQuery(document).scrollTop(), //get page y value 
         header = jQuery(".box_vine"); // your div id
     if(y >= 100)  {
         header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "0", "left" : "0"});
     } else {
         header.css("position", "static");
     }
 });
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What is not working? [ask]

Comment: code work but I need to remove fixed when I'm 100px from footer

Comment: check intersectobserver. You put an empty div with ID absolute position 100px from footer. You check it's intersecting, and you remove fixed

Answer (score 0):

You should get footer's height and check if it's in in your scroll's distance.
It should look like something as the code below:

```
scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()
footerDistance = $('#footer').offset().top;

    if ((scrollDistance - 100) >= footerDistance) {
        // TYPE YOUR CODE HERE
    }
```